# stream multiple body using async sinatra

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, sinatra

I would like start a long poll request from javascript which is fine and i expect my ruby prog to stream multiple body sections to the javascript. Why doesn the following (pseudo)code work?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/async'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'thin'
require 'json'

    class Test < Sinatra:Base
      register Sinatra::Async

      aget '/process' do
        for c in 1..10
          body {
            { :data => [ "this is part #{c}" ] }.to_json
          end
        end
      end

      run!
    end
```

Maybe i misunderstood what long polling and async is supposed to do, but my expectation is that i get multiple bodies sent back to the client ? Do i need to use eventmachine or something?

thanks

Comment: I'm working on this too right now.  From what I understand, body will close the request-writing stream and send it.  If you call `body 'asdf'` twice in a row, you will only see 'asdf' in the page.  I found one lead that suggested using write, or response.write, instead.  That seems to be better as I can see my connection is still open in the browser.  The problem with this is, again, that two `write` calls in a row don't behave as expected.

Comment: **BOUNTY INFO**: I will award the bounty to someone who can either A) Explain why this approach isn't feasible (i.e. because of some HTTP specification, which I suspect).  B) Provide code to write to the body and display this in the browser, then write to the body 2 seconds later and have this update displayed in the browser.  

Please provide a reference or working code, unless you want someone to touch up your answer and get the bounty reward :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response on this but I was picking this work up again (1.5 years later). So the use case here was for example say if you were doing a FTP operation triggered via a webpage. In that webpage I wanted to essentially retrieve the bytes uploaded in realtime. There's plenty of examples using netftp which show the output to a command line. But I think your code shows how it could be done via a webpage. I also want to do that via Ramaze as opposed to Sinatra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/async'
require 'thin'
require 'json'

class Test < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async

  class JSONStream
    include EventMachine::Deferrable

    def stream(object)
      @block.call object.to_json + "\n"
    end

    def each(&block)
      @block = block
    end
  end

  aget '/process' do
    puts 'ok'
    out = JSONStream.new
    body out
    EM.next_tick do
      c = 0
      timer = EM.add_periodic_timer(0.3) do
        c += 1
        out.stream :data => ["this is part #{c}"]
        if c == 100
          timer.cancel
          out.succeed
        end
      end
    end
  end

  run!
end
```

See also: http://confreaks.net/videos/564-scotlandruby2011-real-time-rack

Comment: Still working my way through the talk, but this code works for streaming.  **Thank you** for the quick response (and for doing this talk, I didn't realize this was you until just now).

(StackOverflow requires I wait 6 more hours before I award the bounty)

Comment: By the way, I'd like to help write up some documentation for this procedure so others don't have to spend as much time figuring out this process.  I'm sure I'll also learn some useful information along the way.  Do you have any recommendations on where to put HTTP streaming documentation or what projects to add it to?

Comment: I don't. It's not officially supported by Rack, so good places might be async_sinatra, my async-rack project (which is more of a hack), thin, or well, dunno... some sort of spec for the async extension to rack would be nice, too, to ease implementing it for other servers.

Comment: Also, this approach is feasible. It should in fact yield quite decent performance and is able to handle multiple requests at once.

Comment: Have you read much about HTTP streaming with Rails 3.1?  I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use [the new feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb) with your approach to stream and push components of the body asynchronously.  My impression is that pushing out parts of the body asynchronously could only append data to the bottom of the page--and some client side javascript would be needed to move it elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that's true. To enable streaming with Thin/EventMachine for Rails 3.1, you can use something [like this](https://github.com/rkh/rack-async-stream).

Answer (score 1):

It appears in the [example](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra) below that you need an EventMachine event to trigger the sending of the multiple bodies. Also see this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945739/asynchronously-iterating-over-the-response-of-a-request-using-thin-and-sinatra) as well.

```
require 'sinatra/async'

 class AsyncTest < Sinatra::Base
   register Sinatra::Async

   aget '/' do
     body "hello async"
   end

   aget '/delay/:n' do |n|
     EM.add_timer(n.to_i) { body { "delayed for #{n} seconds" } }
   end

 end
```

Comment: Sorry but how does that send multiple bodies? this just sends a delayed async reponse?

Comment: From what I can tell, this sends one body that's delayed by n seconds.  Perhaps there's some confusion, as gurpal wants to send multiple bodies for one request, or to send one body but in a streaming fashion such that it updates when new data comes in.