# Does HTTP streaming in Rails 3.1 work with Thin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails 3.1 supports HTTP streaming, but only with compatible web servers. The blog post announcing the 3.1 release candidate mentions Unicorn:
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/5/22/rails-3-1-release-candidate

And the API docs also mention Unicorn, and have a stub for Passenger:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb

Does anyone know if Thin is supported, and if so, where I can find configuration info?

Comment: I was able to get Thin to "stream" data.  Take a look at the answer to this [question on pushing asynchronous data to the body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964828/stream-multiple-body-using-async-sinatra/6552070#6552070). As a warning, that approach is more of a hack and isn't technically html5 streaming using `content-type: chunked`, but I've gotten it working on my own machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the release notes for the 0.5.4 release:

```
    == 0.5.4 Flying Mustard release
     * Don't read the full body, use direct streaming when sending response.
       See: Response#each
       As a result, the Content-Length can not be calculated anymore.
       You have to do set this in your adapter. All frameworks do it anyway.
       It improve memory usage and boost speed for low concurrency.
       Thanks to Kent Sibilev and Ezra for their help on that one.
```

However when I ran two thin instances (on different ports, one set as the asset host), the CSS and JS in the layout were not loaded before the `sleep` call in the controller action had finished executing. This was done in production mode.

I'm not 100% sure of the mechanics of it, perhaps the Thin rack-adapter needs to be setup to allow streaming.

Comment: I'm not sure sleeping will work as a test in thin because it will block the reactor and prevent thin from serving anything else while you are sleeping. I could be wrong though.